# Como obter a diferença em segundos com Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sei que para obter a diferença de segundos entre Inicio e Fim é assim: 
**Caso 1:**

```
DECLARE @TB_DIFERENCA_INICIO_FIM as table (
    ID  int,
    DataInicio datetime,
    DataFim datetime
)

INSERT INTO @TB_DIFERENCA_INICIO_FIM VALUES
(1,'2018-10-19 18:18:30.240','2018-10-19 18:18:32.240'),
(2,'2018-10-19 18:18:32.050','2018-10-19 18:18:33.050')

select DATEDIFF(second, DataInicio, DataFim) AS IntervaloEmSegundos from @TB_DIFERENCA_INICIO_FIM
```

**Caso 2:**

A dúvida é para esse caso. 
Preciso saber a diferença entre os 8 registros: 
Explico: 
Qual a diferença entre o Registro 1 e o Registro 2; 
Qual a diferença entre o Registro 2 e o Registro 3, e assim sucessivamente:

```
DECLARE @TB_HORA as table (
    ID  int,
    DataExecucao datetime
)

INSERT INTO @TB_HORA VALUES
(1,'2018-10-19 18:18:30.240'),
(2,'2018-10-19 18:18:29.050'),
(3,'2018-10-19 18:18:29.240'),
(4,'2018-10-19 18:18:28.240'),
(5,'2018-10-19 18:18:27.560'),
(6,'2018-10-19 18:18:25.240'),
(7,'2018-10-19 18:18:24.050'),
(8,'2018-10-19 18:18:24.240')

select * from @TB_HORA
```

**Caso 3:** 
Para o **Caso 2** a solução do [Motta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5005/motta) funciona perfeitamente, porém após analisar a situação real do Banco de Dados que é a seguinte:

```
DECLARE @TB_HORA as table (
    ID  int,
    ID_Servico int,
    DataExecucao datetime
)

INSERT INTO @TB_HORA VALUES
( 1,49,'2018-10-19 18:18:30.313'),
( 2, 1,'2018-10-19 18:18:31.957'),
( 3,33,'2018-10-19 18:18:35.240'),
( 4,49,'2018-10-19 18:18:44.050'),
( 5,53,'2018-10-19 18:18:55.240'),
( 6,53,'2018-10-19 18:18:55.713'),
( 7,49,'2018-10-19 18:18:58.240'),
( 8,51,'2018-10-19 18:18:59.240'),
( 9,54,'2018-10-19 18:19:00.240'),
(10,33,'2018-10-19 18:19:01.240'),
(11,53,'2018-10-19 18:19:05.240')

select DATEDIFF(second, TB1.DataExecucao , TB2.DataExecucao) as intervalo
    from @TB_HORA as TB1
        inner join @TB_HORA as TB2
            on TB1.ID_Servico = TB2.ID_Servico
where TB1.ID_Servico = 49
```

Como podem observar para o **Caso 3** do jeito que está não funciona. 
Preciso retornar a diferença em segundos , por exemplo: somente entre os registros `ID_Servico = 49`.

Comment: Faça um join na mesma tabela com id=id-1

Comment: @Motta agradeço a solução dada, porém encontrei uma situação próxima da realidade e tentei adaptar a sua solução mas não deu certo, daí então alterei o post.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 use o row_number para obter esta sequencia em uma view ou tabela virtual e use este "id"

Comment: Qual é a versão do SQL Server? Se for 2012, ou mais recente, a forma mais simples é usando a função LAG.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Fiz assim:

```
drop table #TB_OK

DECLARE @TB_HORA as table (
    ID  int,
    ID_Servico int,
    DataExecucao datetime
)

INSERT INTO @TB_HORA VALUES
( 1,49,'2018-10-19 18:18:30.313'),
( 2, 1,'2018-10-19 18:18:31.957'),
( 3,33,'2018-10-19 18:18:35.240'),
( 4,49,'2018-10-19 18:18:44.050'),
( 5,53,'2018-10-19 18:18:55.240'),
( 6,53,'2018-10-19 18:18:55.713'),
( 7,49,'2018-10-19 18:18:55.240'),
( 8,51,'2018-10-19 18:18:59.240'),
( 9,54,'2018-10-19 18:19:00.240'),
(10,49,'2018-10-19 18:19:01.240'),
(11,53,'2018-10-19 18:19:05.240')

SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DataExecucao ASC) AS Id,
  ID_Servico, DataExecucao
INTO #TB_OK
FROM @TB_HORA 
WHERE ID_Servico = 49

select DATEDIFF(second, TB1.DataExecucao , TB2.DataExecucao) as Segundos
    from #TB_OK as TB1
        inner join #TB_OK as TB2
            on TB1.Id = TB2.Id-1
```

Créditos ao [Motta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5005/motta)

Answer (score 0):

Eis uma solução para versão 2012 (ou mais recente) do SQL Server.

```
-- código #1
SELECT ID_Serviço, ID, 
       lag (DataExecucao) over (partition by ID_Servico order by ID) as DataExecucao_ant,
       DataExecucao,
       datediff (second, 
                 lag (DataExecucao) over (partition by ID_Servico order by ID),
                DataExecucao) as Intervalo
  from @TB_HORA
  order by ID_Serviço, ID;
```

No artigo “[Funções de janela (*window functions*)](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/10/14/funcoes-de-janela-window-functions/)” você encontra explicação sobre o funcionamento de [LAG](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql), que é uma *window function*.

---

Caso a versão seja anterior a 2012, eis outra solução:

```
-- código #2
with TB_HORA_seq as (
SELECT *, 
       seq= row_number() over (partition by ID_Servico order by ID)
  from @TB_HORA
)
SELECT T1.ID_Serviço, T1.ID, 
       T2.DataExecucao as DataExecucao_ant,
       T1.DataExecucao,
       datediff (second, T2.DataExecucao, T1.DataExecucao) as Intervalo
  from TB_HORA_seq as T1
       left join TB_HORA_seq as T2 on T2.ID_Servico = T1.ID_Servico 
                                      and T2.seq = (T1.seq-1)
  order by T1.ID_Serviço, T1.ID;
```